# Sliding an image from top of a stack of images

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, css-transitions

I want to create a stack of images like that of spotify design homepage (https://spotify.design/)
and remove them one by one on a set of timer. I have looked around everywhere but to no help. Can anyone send me a tutorial or some sort of help I'll be so glad.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without knowing your abilities, but I would look into the z-index css properties and conditional rendering. each card can be at a different z-index and a function on a timer would pop the last one off, setting state to stop it from rendering conditionally.

representing the stack of cards in an array would make it easy to keep track of.